# Regaining focus on Excel after executing VBA in PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am preparing an Excel file in which I run an UserForm aimed at updating PowerPoint Slides. The problem that I have is that at some point after pasting some pictures in the PowerPOint Slides I am calling for Open Dialog window to select a file to embed in the presentation. However excel is not on focus on the time and it starts flashing in the background so the use has to see it and activate it to open the dialog window.

I have tried using Workbook.activate, Select expression and nothing worked.

```
    Dim s As Integer
        For s = MyPresentation.Slides(9).Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            If MyPresentation.Slides(9).Shapes(s).Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
                MyPresentation.Slides(9).Shapes(s).Delete
            End If
        Next s


indexsheet.Activate


Dim Met2FactSheet As String
Dim HerFactSheet As String

MsgBox "Please choose the Metro2 Fact Sheet", vbQuestion, "Metro2 Fact Sheet selection"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
          If .Show <> -1 Then MsgBox "No file selected! Exiting script.": End
        Met2FactSheet = .SelectedItems(1)

    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

My VBA editor is busted at the minute so I can't confirm anything, but try

`AppActivate("Excel.Application")`

or alternatively, try using
`GetObject("Excel.Application")`

to get a handle on the application and then attempt via a different method?

Comment: I receive "Invalid procedure call or argument".

But then I tried AppActivate Application.Caption and it worked.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Update: "Application.Caption" works only if you do not run the script from the editor...